# How to make an "add to cart" popover in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to make an "Add to Cart" in Swift for a retail store. My current issue is that I am trying to pass a 'label' which carries database information from one view controller to another. The issue is that the label carries information. Most tutorials discuss how to pass text fields onto another view controller. I need to pass the information to a popover which will act as a shopping cart.

This is the video I have seen to be most useful however it uses text fields and I need to pass label to label. Or in other words pass that label with the data to the popover.

Thanks in advance for the help

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guSYMPaXLaw&nohtml5=False

Comment: Perhaps if you provided the code you are using and isn't working.    In general its going to try to enforce the Model - View - Controller paradigm.   So, your data should all be in your model.  Perhaps your model should include your state (that you need a popup box with text).   Then your controller will invoke draw the view.. or whatever.   Even if you want to shoehorn in your design... a label is basically text anyway, so you should be able to pass it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass a label between View Controllers. Instead, pass the text attached to the label as a string.

If you take the time to read this tutorial, I guarantee it'll solve your issues.

http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: This is objective c ... I am trying to do all of this in swift ... do you know how to go about doing so in swift ??thanks

Comment: For this matter, Swift and Objective-C are, for all practical purposes, identical. In most cases for beginners, the difference between Swift and Objective-C is negligible. You'll find that the method names and such are the same, and Xcode's autocomplete will hold your hand the whole way.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should *never* use a label to "carry information". Passing data to a view controller should happen through a variable such as a string, int, or custom object, etc. in the view controller you're presenting. Then you can display that data when the view controller has successfully loaded. If you watch the tutorial video you're linking to, the presenter does exactly that. He's passing the data through a string, not a label. He loads the string data into the label when the view controller loads.

If you want the view controller you're displaying to display as a popover, you just change the segue presentation kind to use popover in Interface Builder. You pass the string in the `prepareForSegue:` function just like he tells you in the tutorial. Everything you need is in that tutorial. The only thing you really need to change is the second view controller presentation kind--which should be "Present as Popover" instead of "Show (e.g. Push)".

**Update**

Your question indicates you haven't yet understood how model-view-controller works. The view controller you are trying to display needs to have a variable in it that simply holds the data (model) until it is time to display it (view/view controller). Watch your video and listen for him to discuss a String variable called `LabelText` (it actually should be named `labelText` in order to conform to proper Swift syntax, but that's a different discussion). He starts discussing it around 10 minutes in. It's in the `prepareForSegue:` function where he sets the variable. Then, inside the new view controller, he displays the String variable's content in a label's text field. Think of the String variable as the "placeholder" you're referring to.

Comment: How would you get the string passed to the popover without using a 'place holder' (AKA label) that holds the stored information to the other view controller (pop over) ? In order for me to present my information from the database I need to have a cell that has a placeholder which displays the name of the product which is our label in swift. And when the label is selected it should go to the 'cart', but I am unable to pass the data from the label to the popover. Trying to be as clear as possible. Thanks in advnace